# lucee says existing array does not exist

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, lucee

I am getting two strange errors in code that is quite similar to lots of code that is running fine. The relevant code starts like this:

```
<cfset colvalue  = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('purchase')>
<cfset colarray  = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterValues('xcol')> 
<cfdump var = "#colarray#" label = "purch2 19 colarray">  
<cfdump var = "#colvalue#" label = "purch2 20 colvalue">
```

The dumps show that both arrays are correct.

I then try to run a script using a ridiculously simple function that has been running fine for years.  The structure was set up earlier and a dump shows it is correct.)

```
 <cfset colval = structcol["#xxcol#"]>
 <cfloop array = "#colarray#" index="xxcol"> 
 <cfoutput>
     <script type="text/javascript" >             
        fieldput('#xxcol#' '#colval#')
       </script>
  </cfoutput>
```

The code for the fieldput function:

```
function fieldput(id, val) {
document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
```

This function will not run, either as a function or inline within my script tags.  The console gives me this message: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. ind-purchase2.cfm:525:21; and the same error for all the values in the loop.

The debugger shows all these referenced lines in the middle in the middle of a Lucee error message block.  So if that is where the missing ) is I can't do anything about it.

The Lucee error message itself never appeared in my output and it says: The key [COLARRAY] does not exist, but there is a similar key with name [COLARRAY] available.

I've tried all sorts of things to straighten this out, but the javascript continues not to run, and the non-appearing Lucee error message continues to show in the debugger.

Can anyone explain what is going on or how to fix it?

Comment: missing comma(`,`) between parameters -> `fieldput('#xxcol#', '#colval#')`

Comment: you are so right  -- it just had to be something stupid, but it is hard to see one's own stupidity.